# Can we derive an equation to reflect any point/line over any quadratic function?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, reflection

This is a [derivation](https://www.slideshare.net/hcr1991/reflection-of-a-point-about-a-line-a-plane-in-2d-3d-space-geometry-by-hcr) for reflecting any point over any function with the equation $y=mx+b$. Is it possible to further this to apply to any quadratic function with the equation $y=Ax^2+Bx+C$?

Comment: It's clear what we mean by "reflect a point over a line", but what does it mean to reflect a point over a parabola? This is a rhetorical question: there is at least one good answer, but you need to figure out exactly what you're asking before your question can be answered :)

Comment: And just a word about precision of diction, by which I mean choice of words. You want to reflect about a graph, or about a parabola, not about a function. For, functions are not geometric objects here, but their graphs are.